# How can i write date and time with php in a text file?

Tags: php, date, fwrite

i have a script that allows me to catch IPs.
I need this script for my Website.

```
    <html>
    <body>
     <?php
      $file = "ips.txt";
       $f=fopen($file, 'a');
        fwrite($f,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n"); 
      fclose($f);
     ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It writes the IP into the text file but i want also to see the date and time when the person visited my website. I'm new with php and it was already very hard to do this script, it would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: absolutely zero-effort

Comment: Oh, and keep on reading tutorials. This isn't a school, which you really should get used to keeping track of the good education system they have up there in Deutschland ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the date and append it to your string:

```
fwrite($f,date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ': ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n");
```

Naturally you can format that anyway you would like.

To deal with your timezone issue it gets a bit more complex as you have use `DateTime()` with `DateTimeZone()` to adjust the time accordingly.

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Malta'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
fwrite($f, $date . ': ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is it also possible to change the GMT ? Because it's 02:10 in my country and text file says its 00:10.

Comment: @1337zone.WIN yes it is possible.

Comment: @1337zone.WIN What country are you in?